# AWS API Gateway http proxy endpoint url report error with {proxy}

Tags: amazon-web-services, proxy, aws-api-gateway

AWS API gateway HTTP proxy integration returns the following error when I tried to proxy to another URL.

```
Thu Jul 04 13:34:51 UTC 2019 : Sending request to https://api.example.com/{proxy}
Thu Jul 04 13:34:51 UTC 2019 : Execution failed due to configuration error: Illegal character in path at index 38: https://api.example.com/{proxy}
Thu Jul 04 13:34:51 UTC 2019 : Method completed with status: 500
```

The issue is with `{proxy}`. If that's removed, my API works perfectly. From AWS documentation, they have it the same as well, so i wasn't expecting any issue.

Has anyone met this issue before and how did you resolve it or is there anything else I need set or maybe set wrongly? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Managed to resolve it after more debugging.

I was using Terraform to configure API gateway and i missed out to add request_parameters in both aws_api_gateway_method and aws_api_gateway_integration resources.

Comment: Thank you a lot!
To be more specific on your answer, we should specify:

In aws_api_gateway_method

request_parameters = {
    "method.request.path.proxy" = true
  }

In aws_api_gateway_integration

request_parameters = {
    "integration.request.path.proxy" = "method.request.path.proxy"
  }

Found example here: https://gist.github.com/mendhak/8303d60cbfe8c9bf1905def3ccdb2176

Answer (score 0):

If this configuration is being imported from an open api 3 schema using terraform, then this is how it would look like:

```
/v2/{proxy+}:
    x-amazon-apigateway-any-method:
      parameters:
        - name: "proxy"
          in: "path"
          required: true
          type: "string"
      x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
        uri: "https://api.example.com/{proxy}"
        responses:
          default:
            statusCode: "401"
        requestParameters:
          integration.request.path.proxy: "method.request.path.proxy"
        connectionType: "INTERNET"
        httpMethod: "ANY"
        type: "http_proxy"
```